# How to only insert/update Json to mysql if status success

Tags: php, mysql, json, decode

I want to decode my json data and inserting to mysql table with specific status only. My JSON is:

```
{"status":"success","message":"Hello","username":"jhon","password":"doe"}
```

And the update conditions is the password recorded on the database different from json object.

But if the json response with status failed, no need to insert to my db.

I am really new on this, is it possible to do this. Some tutorials link will also helpful.

Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic because basically you ask us to code this for you, whereas you should use the platform to ask when you come to a specific, reproducible problem.
Another thing is, you should not mess with user passwords. If you can see the password in plaintext, you done something wrong. Read about data security best practice first.

Comment: Thanks to remind me for security, I tried to find the tuts on google. But not specific with this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$myjson = '{"status":"fail","message":"Hello","username":"jhon","password":"doe"}';

$decode = json_decode($myjson);


if($decode->status == "success"){
    echo "Mysql Procced";
}else{
    echo "No Mysql Procced";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue, will try it

Comment: it's my pleasure to answer